# iOS: Building a slideshow with fullscreen images

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to build a slideshow in which you slide images (displayed in fullscreen modality). I was planning to use UIViews and add gesture recognizers.. but I was wondering if there is something already done I can reuse, or any tip.

I would like to have the same effect you have when you slide through open apps on the iPad (you can slide them, and you can slide and you still see part of the first view when the second view comes in. (and in case you are moving back your finger, the first view comes back.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Three20 photo viewer`](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/three20-photo-viewer). You can look at [`this`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) tutorial for help on using it.

There is also a [`WWDC video`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=104) from last year which gives you an idea on how this can be implemented.

There are `other tools` that you can look into. [`Cocoa Controls`](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/) has a fairly exhaustive list of tools that you can use for your projects.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through this stuff. Just a quick question: what's the difference between these libraries and the 3rd party libraries that app store don't accept ? You know what I mean ? Those private libraries that cause your app to be rejected.

Comment: It's hard to vouch for each and every tool there but I expect them to be safe. You can probably check here if you've some doubts. As far I as I've seen, the tools there are an aggregation of what's provided by Apple with some improvisations.

Answer (score 3):

At the most basic level, a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled will work fine for swiping to get to the next image. You'll probably need to be more specific than that.

Comment: Yes, what I need is actually to stop the scrolling on each image boundary, exactly like in the "Photos" application slideshow...

Comment: Have you enabled paging on the scroll view? You need to set the [`pagingEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled) property to `YES`.

Comment: +1 for this. It works well, in case you don't want to use Three20. I have a scroll view in paging mode containing multiple scroll views for each images (so you can zoom in on the images).