# iPhone iOS how to display a slideshow of photos stored in the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, slideshow

I have an app that allows the user to take photos using front facing camera and store them in the app. I would like to offer the user an ability to view all photos in order they were taken one after another.

I know that this should be fairly easy to implement, but from my past experience, there may be hidden orientation issues, etc.  **I would like to know if there are some open source libraries, or apple-provided classes that I can use to display a slideshow of photos to the user?**

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I usually use the following

> NSArray *animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
>       [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.ext"],
>       [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.ext"],
>       ....
>       nil];
>   _imageView.animationImages=animationImages;
>   [_imageView startAnimating];

Here is what I think you might like that I have shamefully copied from here [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372389/ios-building-a-slideshow-with-fullscreen-images)

You can use the [`Three20 photo viewer`](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/three20-photo-viewer). You can look at [`this`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) tutorial for help on using it.

There is also a [`WWDC video`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=104) from last year which gives you an idea on how this can be implemented.

There are [`other tools`](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=photo&commit=Search) that you can look into. [`Cocoa Controls`](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/) has a fairly exhaustive list of tools that you can use for your projects.